# tensorflow for poets: "The name 'import/input' refers to an Operation not in the graph."

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I was following the codelabs tensorflow for poets and the training worked fine but when I runned the script to evaluate a image:

```
python -m scripts.label_image \
    --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb  \
    --image=tf_files/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

I got the following error:

```
The name 'import/input' refers to an Operation not in the graph.
```

I looked around and it has something to do with chosing the input and output layer, the script label_image.py has 'input' and 'output' set as default. The architecture I'm using is 'inception_v3'.

Answer (score 15):

I changed **~/scripts/label_image.py** line 77 and it works:

from

```
input_layer = "input"
```

to

```
input_layer = "Mul"
```

Comment: I worked, but I had to change "input_height = 224" and "input_width = 224" both to 299. How did you figured that out? Using "Mul"

Comment: Worked for me as well... no idea what it actually does though.

Comment: There is a resized_input_layer_name=Mul in line 870 of retrain.py, that is for inception_v3. That is why we need to change the width and height into 299. That is the retrained setting.

Comment: I also changed `output_layer="InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1"` on line `79` to `output_layer = "final_result"`

Answer (score 8):

Use --input_layer name as Placeholder. It will work because the retrain.py script has set default value of input_layer as "Placeholder".

```
    python label_image.py 
          --graph=retrained_graph.pb 
          --labels=retrained_labels.txt 
          --output_layer=final_result 
          --image=testimage654165.jpg 
          --input_layer=Placeholder
```

Comment: Works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Not everyone is getting this error. I'm guessing if you used any other architecture apart from MobileNet this error turns up.
In your label_image.py file 
change the values to:

```
input_height = 299
input_width = 299
input_layer = "Mul"
```

This should solve it.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mimii and @Celio mentioned: change ~/scripts/label_image.py, at the line `input_layer = "input"` to `input_layer = "Mul"` **AND** change the input dimensions: `input_height = 299` and `input_width= 299`

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
curl -LO https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/raw/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py
python label_image.py \
--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt \
--input_layer=Placeholder \
--output_layer=final_result \
--image=$HOME/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make some changes in `label_image.py` in the **scripts** folder

`input_height = 299` Change **input_height** to **299** from **224** 
`input_width = 299`  Change **input_width** to **299** from **224**
`input_mean = 128` 
`input_std = 128` 
`input_layer = "Mul"` Change **input_layer** to **Mul** from **input** 
`output_layer = "final_result"`

**Output:**

`Evaluation time (1-image): 1.901s`

`daisy (score=0.98584)`
`sunflowers (score=0.01136)`
`dandelion (score=0.00210)`
`tulips (score=0.00066)`
`roses (score=0.00004)`

For more info, refer [this page](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/issues/3)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `--output_layer=final_result:0` as parameter.

```
Final call is : python -m scripts.label_image \
--graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb  \
--output_layer=final_result:0 \
--image=tf_files/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! Passing the output_layer as a parameter did not help, I still get the same error while trying to use 'import/input_layer' as a operation in the graph. I printed out all the operations and 'import/input_layer' is not even there, the closest thing is: 
    <tf.Operation 'import/input/BottleneckInputPlaceholder' type=PlaceholderWithDefault>,

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer.
I run python script below with a retrained model. Can you try this one?

Requirements:
**labels.txt  and  output.pb(retrained model) should be at same directory with my python scipt.**
Save code below as test.py
And call it as: **python test.py xxx.jpg**

```
import sys
import tensorflow as tf


image_path = sys.argv[1]


image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()


label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("./labels.txt")]


with tf.gfile.FastGFile("./output.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:



    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})


    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the "retrain.py" code you'll see an argument called '--final_tensor_name'. If you don't pass that argument it will keep 'final_result' or 'Mul' (depending on the version your using) as the default.

The only way to view the input and output names without the actual training output files is to view the graph in TensorBoard of the 'frozen_graph.pb' or in your case the 'retrained_graph.pb' file.

This is a nice way of outputting the required files to view it in TensorBoard.
https://gist.github.com/jubjamie/2eec49ca1e4f58c5310d72918d991ef6

Once you run that code and have the output going to your chosen directory, you can start up TensorBoard and view it in Chrome. Viewing the graph helps me alot since I'm a noob in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can run by command lines with the options without changing codes:

```
python -m scripts.label_image2 --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb -- 
folder_images=../updated_images/testing -- 
labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt --input_layer=Mul -- 
input_height=299 --input_width=299
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting input layer to Mul works for me.  However, it seems to be ignoring my input size settings and doesn't do any magic to resize the image to 299x299 which I guess Mul is expecting.  I did this:

```
set INPUT_WIDTH=194 
set INPUT_HEIGHT=141 
set INPUT_LAYER=Mul 
python -m scripts.label_image --image=%IMAGE% --input_height=%INPUT_HEIGHT% \
--input_width=%INPUT_WIDTH% --graph=%GRAPH% \
--input_layer=%INPUT_LAYER% --output_layer=final_result
```

and got this:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 141, 194, 3) 
for Tensor 'import/Mul:0', which has shape '(1, 299, 299, 3)'
```

And ohhh, looking at the code, input_width and input_height are what to normalize *to*, not to normalize *from*.  So it's all good.  Also I needed to add my labels.