# What is input_layer in tensorflow (label_image)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow to retrain a net. I think I did it correctly (I had the graph and labels).

Now I am using label_image.py to classify an image.
This is the file: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py

I call:

```
py label_image.py --image=test.jpg --graph=retrained_graph.pb --labels=retrained_labels.txt --input_layer=input --output_layer=final_result:0 --input_width=160 --input_height=120
```

but I have this error:

```
The name 'input' refers to an Operation not in the graph.
```

This is the graph I can see with tensorboard [graph tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c1k2.png)

I see people saying: "use Mul/input/placeholder" and other stuff as parameter for "--input_layer=..." but none of them work for me.

i.e. [tensorflow for poets: "The name 'import/input' refers to an Operation not in the graph."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325799/tensorflow-for-poets-the-name-import-input-refers-to-an-operation-not-in-the)

And then I would like to understand what I'm doing...

The same thing maybe apply also for the output layer (I don't have error know, but maybe I will get when the first problem will be solved)

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some research I used what I found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50620593/9419748

to output on monitor all the layers of the graph. In this way I was able to find the exact name of a suitable layer and passing the right name everything works.